# redirect www to non-www on elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed an application, and it is deployed successfully, I want to redirect www to non-www. Currently, I have the following settings

```
RewriteEngine On
<If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</If>
```

How can I get it in elastic beanstalk?